# Install module in Python 2.7 and not in Python 3.3

Tags: python, macos, module, installation

I'm working on mac OS X and I have both Python 2.7 and 3.3 on it. I want to install pykml module and i successfully installed it on python 3.3, but how do I do the same for Python 2.7?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip: dealing with multiple Python versions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/pip-dealing-with-multiple-python-versions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this if pip version >=1.5

`$ pip2.6 install package
 $ pip3.3 install package`

if pip version is between 0.8 and 1.5 this will work

`$ pip-2.7 install package
 $ pip-3.3 install package`

Comment: @Mikhaylova. Awesome.